# Blake2b-512 with ED25519 in PHP with NanoSalt library (Nano Crypto)

Tags: php, cryptography, cryptocurrency, ed25519

I'm trying to generate a Nano private key, public key and address (that's a cryptocurrency) in PHP. I successfully generated private keys but I'm not able to generate the public key and consequently neither the checksum nor the integer address. in order to do this I would have to encrypt the private key through the blake2b-512 algorithm and the ED25119 curve and then I gotta obtain the checksum through the blake2b-40 algorithm by encrypting the public key. That's my code:

```
$privatekey = strtoupper(bin2hex(random_bytes(32)));
$publickey = sodium_crypto_sign_ed25519_pk_to_curve25519($private_key);
$checksum = hash(blake2b-40, $publickey);
```

I didn't get what I need. Why?

**UPDATE 30/12/2021 13:36**

I'm trying to resolve the update with the NanoSalt library but it gives me this error:

index.php

```
<?php
use MikeRow\Salt\NanoSalt;

$nanoSalt = new NanoSalt();
$public_key = $nanoSalt->crypto_sign_public_from_secret_key(hex2bin("781186FB9EF17DB6E3D1056550D9FAE5D5BBADA6A6BC370E4CBB938B1DC71DA3"));
print(strtoupper($public_key->toHex()) . PHP_EOL);
?>
```

and that's the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "MikeRow\Salt\NanoSalt" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Peppe\index.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Peppe\index.php on line 4
```

Comment: Ed25519 uses SHA512 to derive the public key from the seed, while Nano applies Blake2b/512. Therefore `sodium_crypto_sign_publickey_from_secretkey()` will not work for Nano (and `sodium_crypto_sign_ed25519_pk_to_curve25519()` won't work anyway, since this performs an X25519 key conversion).

Comment: what do you suggest me to do? Is there any extension to this?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer. There I have pointed out some approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Nano* does not use the standard Ed25519, but a variant where the digest Blake2b-512 is used instead of the usual SHA-512, see [standard variant](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/54367) vs [Nano variant](https://docs.nano.org/integration-guides/the-basics/#account-public-key).

For this reason, standard *Libsodium* libraries could generally not be used, such as the [`sodium_crypto_sign_publickey_from_secretkey()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sodium-crypto-sign-publickey-from-secretkey.php) function proposed in the other answer. Apart from that, this function expects a 64 bytes key (consisting of seed and public key) while in Nano the private key is only 32 bytes (consisting of the seed).

---

The following [example](https://docs.nano.org/integration-guides/key-management/#expanding-private-keys) from the Nano documentation shows a private key, a public key and a public address:

```
"private": "781186FB9EF17DB6E3D1056550D9FAE5D5BBADA6A6BC370E4CBB938B1DC71DA3",
"public": "3068BB1CA04525BB0E416C485FE6A67FD52540227D267CC8B6E8DA958A7FA039",
"account": "nano_1e5aqegc1jb7qe964u4adzmcezyo6o146zb8hm6dft8tkp79za3sxwjym5rx"
```

---

One way to get the public key with PHP is to use a library that supports Nano. Such a library is e.g. [*Salt*](https://github.com/MikeRow/Salt), which also contains the [Nano variant](https://github.com/MikeRow/Salt/blob/v1.0.7/src/NanoSalt.php). With this library the determination of the public key is simply:

```php
use MikeRow\Salt\NanoSalt;

$nanoSalt = new NanoSalt();
$public_key = $nanoSalt->crypto_sign_public_from_secret_key(hex2bin("781186FB9EF17DB6E3D1056550D9FAE5D5BBADA6A6BC370E4CBB938B1DC71DA3"));
print(strtoupper($public_key->toHex()) . PHP_EOL); // 3068BB1CA04525BB0E416C485FE6A67FD52540227D267CC8B6E8DA958A7FA039
```

Using the private key from the example results in the public key from the example.

Another way to get the public key would be to use a library that supports Ed25519 arithmetic, so that the public key can be obtained by multiplying by the base point. Such a library is e.g. [*phpseclib*](https://api.phpseclib.com/master/phpseclib3/Crypt/EC/Curves/Ed25519.html) (although frankly I have not tested this way).

---

The public address is obtained by encoding the public key with a special Base32 variant and appending a checksum that is also Base32 encoded. The checksum is the Blake2b-40 hash of the public key, see [here](https://docs.nano.org/integration-guides/the-basics/#account-public-address).

A library that supports the special Base32 variant and Blake2b is [*NanoPHP*](https://github.com/MikeRow/NanoPHP). Since the Blake2b implementation is a bit cumbersome, this [*Blake2b*](https://github.com/deemru/Blake2b) library can be used alternatively. A possible implementation is:

```php
require "Uint.php";
require "Blake2b.php";

// publick key
$public_key = "3068bb1ca04525bb0e416c485fe6a67fd52540227d267cc8b6e8da958a7fa039";
$key = Uint::fromHex('0' . $public_key);
$key_base32 = $key->toString();
print($key_base32 . PHP_EOL);

// checksum
$blake40 = new Blake2b(5);
$hash = $blake40->hash(hex2bin($public_key));
$check = Uint::fromHex(bin2hex($hash))->reverse();
$check_base32 = $check->toString();
print($check_base32 . PHP_EOL);

print('nano_' . $key_base32 . $check_base32 . PHP_EOL); // nano_1e5aqegc1jb7qe964u4adzmcezyo6o146zb8hm6dft8tkp79za3sxwjym5rx
```

where *Uint.php* provides the Base32 encoding and comes from the *NanoPHP* library, while *Blake2b.php* is the more handy Blake2b alternative.

Using the public key from the example gives the correct address.

---

To test other private keys, [this site](https://nanoo.tools/key-address-seed-converter) is useful.

---

Regarding security: Be aware that all libraries used are rather small and may contain vulnerabilities.

Comment: Salt library looks so bad, when I install it give me many errors.

Comment: @Alessandro - In your meanwhile deleted comment you mention PHP 8 (which you did not specify in your question btw). I have not had any problems under PHP 7, but PHP 8 I frankly haven't tested. There are not so many libraries that support Nano, and probably even less that are compatible with PHP 8 (released a year ago). If you don't find any, and you need PHP 8, your only options are to implement the needed functionality yourself (e.g. using _phpseclib_) or try to port the _Salt_ library to PHP 8. Both probably mean a corresponding effort.

Comment: Please check my update. I tested it in PHP7 but it gives me many errors.

Comment: In my environment (Windows, Eclipse) there were no larger problems when installing the _Salt_ library (I just tested again). The only thing was that in _NanoSalt.php_ the `Exception` type could not be resolved, which can be solved with a `use Exception`. Maybe it's the same in your IDE. But in general the details of the import will depend on the IDE you're using. If you still have problems, you should ask a separate question about this, providing all needed info. The library import has nothing to do with the actual problem and would be beyond the scope of the current question.

Comment: - Do i also need to add a `require_once 'vendor/mikerow/salt/src/NanoSalt.php';` in the index.php ?

Comment: @Alessandro - I don't know your specific IDE and project architecture and can't answer this question. Just try it out. And if it doesn't work or if you have new problems, post a new question with **all** the information needed to answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I opened another thread.

Comment: Problem solved! The library apparently has compatibility issues with PHP8. But with PHP7 it works perfectly. Thanks to Topaco for the help.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7 >= 7.2.0 and PHP 8 do have a built-in crypto library "sodium" that let you derive the ED25519 public key from a given secret (private) key: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sodium-crypto-sign-publickey-from-secretkey.php

Below is a full runing example for this task:

```
<?php
function generateEd25519KeyPair()
{
    return sodium_crypto_sign_keypair();
}

function deriveEd25519PublicKey($privateKey)
{
    return sodium_crypto_sign_publickey_from_secretkey ($privateKey);
}

function base64Encoding($input)
{
    return base64_encode($input);
}

echo 'Generate ED25519 private and public key and derive public key from private key' . PHP_EOL;
$keyPair = generateEd25519KeyPair();
$privateKey = sodium_crypto_sign_secretkey($keyPair);
$publicKey = sodium_crypto_sign_publickey($keyPair);
echo'privateKey (Base64): ' . base64Encoding($privateKey) . PHP_EOL;
echo'publicKey (Base64):  ' . base64Encoding($publicKey) . PHP_EOL;

echo PHP_EOL . 'derive the publicKey from the privateKey' . PHP_EOL;
$publicKeyDerived = deriveEd25519PublicKey($privateKey);
echo'publicKey (Base64):  ' . base64Encoding($publicKeyDerived) . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Comment: It return this error: "Call to undefined function sodium_crypto_sign_publickey_from_secretkey()"

Comment: Did you enable the sodium extension on your PHP server? Which version of PHP are you running?

Comment: I'm using PHP 8 and I don't have a server, I've a free web-hosting in which I cannot setup extensions