# Problems with the NanoSalt library [PHP]

Tags: php, cryptography, salt

I'm trying to setup the [NanoSalt](https://github.com/MikeRow/Salt) library on XAMPP with PHP 8.1

It return to me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "MikeRow\Salt\Exception" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Peppe\vendor\mikerow\salt\src\NanoSalt.php:28 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Peppe\index.php(3): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Peppe\vendor\mikerow\salt\src\NanoSalt.php on line 28
```

That's my index.php content:

```
<?php
use MikeRow\Salt\NanoSalt;
require_once "vendor/mikerow/salt/src/NanoSalt.php";

$nanoSalt = new NanoSalt();
$public_key = $nanoSalt->crypto_sign_public_from_secret_key(hex2bin("781186FB9EF17DB6E3D1056550D9FAE5D5BBADA6A6BC370E4CBB938B1DC71DA3"));
print(strtoupper($public_key->toHex()) . PHP_EOL);

?>
```

How can I resolve that?

Comment: When using composer, you don't require individual files. Instead, require the automatically generated `vendor/autoload.php` file.

Comment: @ChrisHaas - It didn't helped, that's new error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "MikeRow\Salt\Exception" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Peppe\vendor\mikerow\salt\src\NanoSalt.php:28 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Peppe\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(571): include() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Peppe\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Peppe\index.php(5): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('MikeRow\\Salt\\Na...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Peppe\vendor\mikerow\salt\src\NanoSalt.php on line 28`

Comment: Oh, I see now. First, that code is archived, so the author is probably not maintaining it, and I wouldn't recommend using it. You will need to hack the files, the `Exception` class on [line 28](https://github.com/MikeRow/Salt/blob/e7835f690dbac35dc2f5b8cbb9a03c0b1e8de9ba/src/NanoSalt.php#L28) needs a leading "\", or you can bring it into scope with a `use` statement. There might be other problems of a similar nature in there, too.

Comment: A new error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MikeRow\Salt\FieldElement::rewind() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Peppe\vendor\mikerow\salt\src\FieldElement.php:21 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Peppe\vendor\mikerow\salt\src\NanoSalt.php(300): MikeRow\Salt\FieldElement->toString() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Peppe\index.php(6): MikeRow\Salt\NanoSalt->crypto_sign_public_from_secret_key(Object(MikeRow\Salt\FieldElement)) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Peppe\vendor\mikerow\salt\src\FieldElement.php on line 21`

Comment: I'm sorry, the package you are trying to use appears to have several bugs. I would recommend not using it, or contact the author. Fixing each one here doesn't seem useful.

Comment: The library works under PHP7 (apart from the minor bug described in the comment) and the posted code can be executed successfully (tested in Eclipse and installed using composer). However, it does not seem to be PHP8 compatible.

Comment: @Topaco, when I run the `composer require mikerow/salt`, and then run the most basic PHP example of `require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';new MikeRow\Salt\NanoSalt();`, I receive a fatal error for a class not found, regardless of the PHP version (7.3 and 8.0 tested). Are you not getting that?

Comment: @ChrisHaas - I use Eclipse, which allows the creation of a PHP project from a composer package. This is probably more or less functionally equivalent to _composer require mikerow/salt_. The code can be successfully executed if a `require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';` is added (after fixing the `use Exception` issue). But yes, the `require_once "vendor/mikerow/salt/src/NanoSalt.php"` must be omitted. I was referring to the [original code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70522833/9014097) in my last comment and unfortunately forgot that `require_once` that the OP has added.